# solving a system of equations with invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

The nxn matrix A is known to satisfy $A^2-5A+6I=0$, and $A-2I$ is invertible. Solve the system of equations $Ax=3x$

So to solve, I factored the equation into $(A-2I)(A-3I)$. Since $(A-2I)$ is invertible I can mulitply both sides of the equation by $(A-2I)$^(-1) leaving $(A-3I)=0$ . This means that $A=3I$. Did I solve it? Does this mean that x=I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x$ is supposed to be a vector of length $n$, but $I$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

You did correctly show that $A-3I = 0$. Now, you need to find all vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 3x$.

Hint: $Ax = 3x$ is equivalent to $(A-3I)x = Ax-3x = 0$. For which vectors $x$ is that true?

Comment: It seems like x could be any vector of length n since $(A-3I)=0$

Comment: @JenniferB exactly.  So, the solution is "all $x$".